# How does one carry out the Wilcoxon-Gehan test for paired survival data?

Tags: survival, sas, crossover-study

In a 2-way crossover scenario, where subjects are randomized in a 1:1 ratio to either a AB or BA sequence, a time-to-response variable was measured after the dosing of treatment A or treatment B.

Each subject will have a time obtained from treatment A and treatment B respectively.

Feingold and Gillespie (1996) suggested a method to compare the difference in survival times between the two treatments, which is essentially an extension to the Wilcoxon-Gehan rank sum test for paired data.

I am trying to implement this method with SAS, but there is not a PROC I am aware of for this test. Does anyone have any experience using SAS for this test?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You might get a better response on a SAS-specific forum.

Comment: Can you please recommend a forum for me? Thanks.